# Add textfiled and Send Button (mail to) in xcode

Tags: swift, tableview, textfield

i'm build a simple app that allows you to reserve information equipment or a seat in a classroom. In my table view i insert an image and some text. How can i add a text field and a button in the bottom that send me a mail with the summary of the booking?

This is the code that i build until now.

**TableViewController**

```
import UIKit
struct CellData {
    let image : UIImage?
    let message : String?
}
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var data = [CellData] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    data = [CellData.init(image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "printer"), message: "Stampante 3D"),CellData.init(image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "printer"), message: "Stampante 3D"),CellData.init(image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "printer"), message: "Stampante 3D")]

    self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! CustomCell
    cell.mainImage = data[indexPath.row].image
    cell.message = data[indexPath.row].message
    cell.layoutSubviews()
    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
}
```

**Custom Cell**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var message : String?
var mainImage : UIImage?

var messageView : UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return textView
}()

var mainImageView : UIImageView = {
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(mainImageView)
    self.addSubview(messageView)

    mainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    mainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true


    messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainImageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let message = message {
        messageView.text = message
    }
    if let image = mainImage{
        mainImageView.image = image
}        }



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are referring to create a chat like window, if this is correct, one way to resolve this is add handlers for the keyboard events, in order to move the top views. In this case you can start with the following ones:

First you need to add some observers to the Notification center to listen when the keyboard is shown or when is hidden.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)            
    }
```

Then, you need to create the functions to be triggered when the events occurs. As you can see in the following code, the view frame of the view is modified accordingly to the keyboardSize.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {            
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    }            
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```

So, just for clarification, you need to create a second view below the table, in which you will add the textfield and the send button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is now clear how the function works to hide the keyboard. 
https://imageshack.com/a/img924/9216/dyCLpU.png This is what I would like to get. Also in this case I have to add a second view for the text filed and for the button?

Comment: Well, it depends totally in your design. The most common way to do that is adding the UITextField (or UITextView) and the UIButton in the same UIView, which will works as a container. Examples of this behavior are apps like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger.

Comment: In your case, the bottom tabs will be a problem because collide with the desired behavior. This has turn your issue in a UI/UX problem.

Comment: What do you think if I decided to set 3 images, 3 labels, 3 text filed horizontally? I put the button right under it. I believe that the keyboard would not cover these elements and that everything can work.